# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (INSTALL):INSTALL DIRECTORY given no DESTINATION

Tags: c#, cmake

Executing `cmake` gives the following error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (INSTALL):INSTALL DIRECTORY given no DESTINATION

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
INSTALL(DIRECTORY "D:/Niftyrec/install/" DESTINATION ${MEX_INSTALL_DIR_NIFTYREC})
```

Comment: Please go through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The variable `MEX_INSTALL_DIR_NIFTYREC` is not set. Thus, the command `INSTALL(DIRECTORY "D:/Niftyrec/install/" DESTINATION ${MEX_INSTALL_DIR_NIFTYREC})` comes down to `INSTALL(DIRECTORY "D:/Niftyrec/install/" DESTINATION )`. You need to set the variable before.

Answer (score 1):

As @Stanley F. stated, you cannot provide the `INSTALL` CMake command an empty `DESTINATION` path. Although you may have defined `MEX_INSTALL_DIR_NIFTYREC` earlier in your CMake file using the [`set`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) command, it appears it wasn't set correctly.

You can verify the contents of variables before using them by printing them using [`message`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html); it is great for debugging your code:

```
message(STATUS "Install directory: ${MEX_INSTALL_DIR_NIFTYREC}")
INSTALL(DIRECTORY "D:/Niftyrec/install/" DESTINATION ${MEX_INSTALL_DIR_NIFTYREC})
```